# About reduction of PHP Query

Tags: php, sql

I am trying the following query, it works fine, but is there some way to reduce it?

```
<?php
$c_qr="
    SELECT count(profit) AS 'y_c'
        ,profit AS 'x_c'
    FROM account
    WHERE profit = 'excellent'

    UNION

    SELECT count(profit) AS 'c1'
        ,profit AS 'c2'
    FROM account
    WHERE profit = 'fair'

    UNION

    SELECT count(profit) AS 'c1'
        ,profit AS 'c2'
    FROM account
    WHERE profit = 'bad'

    UNION

    SELECT count(sale) AS 'c1'
        ,sale AS 'c2'
    FROM account
    WHERE sale = 'excellent'

    UNION

    SELECT count(sale) AS 'c1'
        ,sale AS 'c2'
    FROM account
    WHERE sale = 'fair'

    UNION

    SELECT count(sale) AS 'c1'
        ,sale AS 'c2'
    FROM account
    WHERE sale = 'bad'

    UNION

    SELECT count(purchase) AS 'c1'
        ,purchase AS 'c2'
    FROM account
    WHERE purchase = 'excellent'

    UNION

    SELECT count(purchase) AS 'c1'
        ,purchase AS 'c2'
    FROM account
    WHERE purchase = 'fair'

    UNION

    SELECT count(purchase) AS 'c1'
        ,sale AS 'c2'
    FROM account
    WHERE purchase = 'bad'
";
```

Comment: You can make a SQL query more readable by having it over multiple lines. Single line queries can be hard to read when they get too long.

Comment: Please provide the table `account` structure. Also, is there any `purchase` value that you are not using in `WHERE` condition?

Comment: I've decided to give you the benefit of doubt but I was tempted to remove the PHP tag since this is obviously a SQL question.

Comment: Maybe you could do three unions and group by the `purchase`, `sale`, and `profit`?

Comment: I don't know how to group

Comment: You need to let us know a bit more about the structure of you table, your output and what you want to achieve. While we could refactor this we are not sure how you want it to look.

Comment: I am using this query to display graphs. Here 'purchase' is the column name and "excellent" , "fair" ,"bad" are its values. It display the graph for one column but i want to display the graph for all coumns like sale, purchase, profit, loss. If i am using the single query to display all columns in one graph then it is too too lenghty. So, is there any another way to do this?